# pass URL built in php as json to ajax for opening in new tab

Tags: php, ajax, json

how to return URL built in php as json object to ajax to open it in the new tab?

so far all my attempts to do so were unsuccessful. Please help

here is my JS file

```
$(document).ready ( function() {

    $('.promoCode').click(function() {

        // Store values in variables
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        var name = form.find('input[name=name]');
        var id = form.find('input[name=id]');
        var submitted = form.find('input[name=submitted]');
        var visitor = form.find('input[name=visitor]');

        // Organize data
        var data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&id=' + id.val() + '&submitted=' + submitted.val() + '&visitor=' + visitor.val();

        var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/includes/_db_get_promo_code.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                myWindow = window.open(encodeURIComponent(true),
                    "_blank");
                myWindow.focus();
                if (html == "true") {

                } else {
                        form.find('.error').fadeIn(500).delay(4000).fadeOut(500);
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {

                alert("Form Error: " + error);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

and here is my PHP file

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/sitewide-variables.php");
// Check if form was submitted
if ($_POST['submitted'] && $_POST['visitor'] == '') {

    // Check if all required fields are filled in
    if (empty($_POST['name']) && empty($_POST['id'])) {
        echo "Error: You must fill in all required fields.";
        // If not, exit!
        exit();
    }
    // If valid, store values in variables
    $id = stripslashes($_POST['id']);
    $name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);

if($name){
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM files_paid WHERE parentpageID = :promoproductID';
    $res = $db->prepare($query);
    $res->execute(array(':promoproductID' => $id));
    foreach ($res as $info);

    if($info['promoCode'] == $_POST['name']){
        $redirect_link = 'http://'.$info['promobuylinkID'].'.myid.pay.clickbank.net';

    $todayis = date("l, F j, Y, g:i a") ;
    $to = "My Email Address";
    $subject = "Promotional Purchase";
    $message = "$todayis [EST] \n
                Promo Code: $name \n
                ";
    // Send email
    $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message);

    if($sent) {
        echo json_encode($redirect_link);

    } else {
        echo "Error: Mail could not be send.";
        exit();
    }
} else {
    echo "Error: There was a problem with submitting the form";
    exit();
}
}
}
?>
```

I am only getting `true` in the new window.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have have found the problem.

First, I was missing dataType: "json", in ajax.

and after that I only had to return html to get to the point where I needed to get.

So the JS file now looks like this

```
$(document).ready ( function() {

    $('.promoCode').click(function() {

        // Store values in variables
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        var name = form.find('input[name=name]');
        var id = form.find('input[name=id]');
        var submitted = form.find('input[name=submitted]');
        var visitor = form.find('input[name=visitor]');

        // Organize data
        var data = 'name=' + name.val() + '&id=' + id.val() + '&submitted=' + submitted.val() + '&visitor=' + visitor.val();

        var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/includes/_db_get_promo_code.php",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                if (html) {
                    window.open(decodeURIComponent(html),"_blank").focus();
                } else {
                        form.find('.error').fadeIn(500).delay(4000).fadeOut(500);
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Your Coupon Code is not valid");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

All works just fine.